# Is there any way to print a (if -else) condition in a for loop without printing it twice?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a problem where i need to input n numbers in a array and need to find is the value of the array is whether odd or even (means 2 2 2 2 will accepted but 1 2 1 3 will not gonna accepted cz it has both even and odd number) but when i am trying to print the value it is showing yesyesyes how can i do it??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int t,n,a[1000],i;
scanf("%d",&t);
if(t>=1 && t<=100)
{
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n>=2 && n<=50)
 {
 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
     {
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  if(a[i]%2==0)
    {
        break;
    }
   if(a[i]%2!=0)
    {
        break;
    }

     else
        printf("NO");

     }

  printf("YES");
 }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I recommend formatting your code so it's easier to read, perhaps [this](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Formatting).

Comment: `need to find is the value of the array`, What does that mean?. All elements are Even or all elements Odd?

Comment: You have `if(a[i]%2==0) { break; } if(a[i]%2!=0) { break; }` If one condition is true then the other will be false. Always.

Comment: What is the purpose of `t`, and checking that it is the range of [1, 100]? Why is `n` limited to 50 entries (when `a` has space for 1000), and why are you placing values in the array starting from the second element?

Answer (score 1):

I presume the problem statement:

**Task**: To find if all the elements in a given list are `all-odd` or `all-even`.

- There are `T` test cases, `1 <= T <= 100`
- In each test case `N` specifying the number of elements in a list(array), `2 <= N <= 50`
- Followed by `N` space separated integers.
- For each test case print `YES` if all list-members are `all-odd` or `all-even`. Print `NO` otherwise.

1. Since the inputs are curated, we're assuming `scanf()` always succeeds.
2. We don't need to store numbers in an array, as we don't need them later.

Simplified code :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
    int T;      // number of tests
    scanf ("%d", &T);

    while (T--) {
        int N;  // numbers in a given test
        scanf ("%d", &N);
        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;
        for (int ni = 0; ni++ < N; ) {
            int X;
            scanf ("%d", &X);
            (X % 2) ? ++odd : ++even;
            //if (odd && even) break; // but, you need to clear the inputs before next test case
        }
        if (N == odd || N == even)
            printf ("YES\n");
        else
            printf ("NO\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For input file:

```
3
4
2 2 2 2 
4
1 2 1 3
5
1 5 7 33 5
```

Output will be:

```
YES
NO
YES
```